# разное поведение Koa приложения в браузерах

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, koa.js

простое приложение Koa

````
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log('>> one');
  await next();
  console.log('<< one');
});

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log('>> two');
  ctx.body = 'two';
  await next();
  console.log('<< two');
});

app.listen(3000);```


*... в Internet Explorer 11 выводит в консоль:*

>> one
>> two
<< two
<< one

*... во всех остальных бразузерах (Chrome, Firefox) вывод в консоль дублируется *

>> one
>> two
<< two
<< one
>> one
>> two
<< two
<< one


*почему так? Спасибо за ответ*
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954326/4496422